# android - get item(position) in adapter returns null

Tags: android

I wrote an activity that downloads an image into a Bitmap object, using ImageLoaderConfiguration library. That is working OK.

My next stage was to create 5 GalleryItem objects and put the Bitmap into those objects.

Finally, I created a GalleryItemAdapter object, that extends ArrayAdapter.

The problem is that in the function getView, `getItem(position)` returns null.

Here is the code:

mainActivity:

```
package com.example.downloadimages;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.listener.SimpleImageLoadingListener;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public String mUrl;
    public Byte [] mImageBytes;
    GalleryItem [] mGalleryItem;
    Bitmap mBitmap;
    public GridView mGridView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.image_view_in_layout);
                mGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
                mUrl = "http://www.royalcanin.in/var/royalcanin/storage/images/breeds/cat-breeds/norwegian-forest-cat/19311843-15-eng-GB/norwegian-forest-cat_cat_breed_cat_picture.jpg";

                ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this) .build();
                ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
                ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(mUrl, new SimpleImageLoadingListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                        mBitmap = loadedImage;
                        mGalleryItem = new GalleryItem[5];
                        for(GalleryItem gi : mGalleryItem)
                        {
                            gi = new GalleryItem();
                            gi.setBitmap(mBitmap);
                        }
                        setupAdapter();
                    }
                });
        }

        void setupAdapter()
        {
            if ( mGridView == null) return;
            mGridView.setAdapter(new GalleryItemAdapter(mGalleryItem)); 
        }

        private class GalleryItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GalleryItem>
        {
            public GalleryItemAdapter(GalleryItem[] mGalleryItem) 
            {
                super(getApplicationContext(), 0, mGalleryItem);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
            {
                convertView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                GalleryItem item = getItem(position);
                ((ImageView) convertView).setImageBitmap(item.getBitmap());
                return convertView;
            }
        }
}
```

class GalleryItem:

```
public class GalleryItem {

    Bitmap bitmap;

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return bitmap;
    }

    public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }
}
```

image_view_in_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

     <GridView 
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="120dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >

    </GridView>
  </LinearLayout
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your adapter code is wrong. you are trying to set bitmap to an ImageView in your activities xml. You need to create new ImageView in the adapter and return it. You can look at here https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Comment: i changed my getView method code, and it still dosent work. this is the new code:  GalleryItem item = getItem(position);
    convertView =  LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_view_in_layout, parent, false);
    ImageView im = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    im.setImageBitmap(item.getBitmap());
    return convertView;

Comment: only other thing that I can think of is change the for each loop to  regular for loop.

Comment: it works! probably, it's not possible to change the target of pointers in a for each loop.

Comment: please select the answer as selected answer.